# How should I tag "I can't find the error" like questions where the answers are workarounds for an IDE bug?

Tags: discussion, tags

The Google Apps Script web IDE has some open issues related to the use of the new runtime (Chrome V8), so some answers give specific workarounds for the error / [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcve) included in the question.

Two examples of *"simple", but not specific,* workarounds are

- When the OP uses JavaScript features supported by the old runtime, switch to the old runtime.
- When the OP uses JavaScript features that aren't supported by the old runtime, use CLASP to use another IDE.

Some questions might be marked as duplicates of an appropriate question, but some of them might already have more specific workarounds based on details included in the question.

Is a workaround for a currently open issue in an IDE a good reason to add additional tags to the question because the issue requires the use of other IDEs and/or debugging techniques?

What about adding one or more of the following tags on these questions *when editing the question* to fix other issues?

Below each tag is the corresponding current tag excerpt

- [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugging) 
  <sub>Debugging is a methodical process of finding and fixing bugs in a computer program. **IMPORTANT NOTE:** This tag is ONLY for questions about debugging techniques or the process of debugging itself, NOT for requesting help debugging your code.</sub>
- [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) 
  <sub>IDEs (Integrated Development Environment) are computer programs that facilitate efficient software development by providing features beyond those of a simple text editor.</sub>

---

For questions where Google Apps Script is used and the workaround involves the use of CLASP, a specific IDE

- [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) this tag should be "mandatory" for questions when Google Apps Script is relevant. Usually this is the main reason to edit this kind of question. 
  <sub>Use for questions about Google Apps Script, Google's JavaScript-based cloud scripting platform for automating tasks across Google products and third-party services. Use in addition to relevant product-specific (e.g. [google-sheets], [google-docs]) or API-specific (e.g. [google-sheets-api]) tags where possible.</sub>
- [clasp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clasp) 
  <sub>Use for questions regarding Clasp, Google's local platform solution for writing Google-apps-script.</sub>
- [visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) (the CLASP documentation includes instructions to add Google Apps Script's Classes autocomplete to this IDE) 
  <sub>Visual Studio Code is an open source text editor available for Linux, OS X, and Windows. It includes support for debugging, embedded Git Control, various extensions and rich development experiences such as intelligent code completion. It is open source driven by Microsoft, built on Electron like GitHub's Atom.</sub>

Comment: I would say that if the ide has a bug, it should reside in their bug tracker. SO is a terrible way for the developer to discover that their software is broken. (And yes, it happened)

Comment: @Braiam Unfortunately the Google Apps Script Issue tracker is not easy to use. Issues have never appeared on Google results for me, sometimes they either appeared when I navigated from the Google Apps Script docs to the issue tracker and search from there but I was able to learn about these issues after someone included a link to the issue on a SO post/comment. Here is one of those issues [Debug mode not responsive in v8](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161887507)

Comment: Probably because it [is not meant to be used by the public](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker). Chromium issue tracker is the opposite of that. BTW, if it doesn't appear in your searches organically, you may use `site:issuetracker.google.com`

Comment: From the link: Intended audience
Issue Tracker is intended for two sets of users:

Public users of a limited set of approved projects designated by Google

Comment: `site:issuetracker.google.com getWidth` returns zero results, but there are several issues about this method.

Comment: Well, apparently they don't allow search engines to scrape the page. Looking for `site:issuetracker.google.com` I only could find login pages :(

Comment: Ugh, it's more horrible than that. They seem to heavily imply that you can have only two types of issues against the tracker: remove requests and gdpr like requests.

Comment: The worst thing is that the issue tracker threads have a lot of "+1", "Me too", complains about how Google handle certain issue... so sometimes it's terrible to find a workaround there, if there is any.